# Azure Function V2 Service Bus Message Deferral

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, messaging, azureservicebus

I am attempting to convert my v1 function to a v2 function, but I cannot find a replacement for deferring a message.

In V1 of Azure Functions it was a method on the `BrokeredMesage` called `.DeferAsync()`. In V2 there is no longer a `BrokeredMessage` but just a `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Message` and this does not contain the method of `.DeferAsync()`.

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-deferral):

> The API is BrokeredMessage.Defer or BrokeredMessage.DeferAsync in the .NET Framework client, MessageReceiver.DeferAsync in the .NET Standard client, and mesageReceiver.defer or messageReceiver.deferSync in the Java client.

But how can I get access to the MessageReciever?
Here is an example of my function:

```
[FunctionName("MyFunction")]
public static void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("topic", "subscription", Connection = "AzureServiceBusPrimary")]Message message, ILogger log)
{
    //Code
}
```

So does anyone know how to defer a V2 `Message` that is triggered from the Azure Service Bus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you mention, the new message receiver offers an async defer method and you can add this to your function by using the following code:

```
[FunctionName("MyFunction")]
public static async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger("topic", "subscription", Connection = "AzureServiceBusPrimary")]Message message, string lockToken, MessageReceiver messageReceiver, ILogger log)
{
    //Your function logic
    await messageReceiver.DeferAsync(lockToken);
}
```

Comment: Where did you find the documentation for this?

Comment: Sorry i could not provide the documentation source as i found this when i was implementing a custom retry logic for my v2 functions and saw an implementation code using it. I have not found a documentation source that will detail this but if someone has please share on the comments.

Comment: No documentation as if today, but it's injected by the Functions SDK in addition to [metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus#trigger---message-metadata) that is diviners. I've captured it my blog post [here](https://weblogs.asp.net/sfeldman/transactional-messaging-with-azure-functions-and-service-bus). Audio, there's an [issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/32126) to add it to the documentation.

Comment: The Functions team is working on documentation for the Service Bus trigger to clarify that you can bind to the `MessageReceiver` class. From there, the `DeferAsync()` method is documented as part of the SDK documentation. The issue for this documentation improvement is here: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/32126.

Comment: For some reason this does not work on my side. I get an error that the message is already completed so the lockToken is already expired. See my post: [Defer message in azure function V2: The lock supplied is invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63179056/defer-message-in-azure-function-v2-the-lock-supplied-is-invalid)

Comment: What will Defer do? Will the message come back again in the Azure Function after lets say x minutes where x can be configured? Thanks.

Comment: @user1685304 No, what you are describing is what the scheduling functionality is for, a great article about this topic can be found here https://www.pmichaels.net/2021/02/27/deferred-messages-in-azure-service-bus/ TL;DR: when you schedule a message, you’re telling the Service Bus to deliver that message at a time of your choosing, when you defer a message, you telling the Service Bus to hang onto a message that has been sent, until such time as you’re ready to receive it.